# .NET, to SendGrid, to Gmail getting From Header missing

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, gmail, sendgrid

I received this message below within SendGrid that was being sent to Gmail.  However this has always worked, and of course I am have a FROM email address included.  Is this something else or a bug?

```
550 5.7.1 [208.117.55.132 11] Our system has detected that this message is not RFC 5322 compliant: 'From' header is missing. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit https://support.google.com/mail/?p=RfcMessageNonCompliant and review RFC 5322 specifications for more information. k7si5926825iok.8 - gsmtp
```

Comment: It would help if you could post the headers from a message that failed its delivery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue with PHP sending via SendGrid to Gmail.  It seems to be solved by changing the From header to have the email address in between < and >.

Old:

```
From: someone@example.com
```

New:

```
From: <someone@example.com>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like SendGrid are having issues with this today.

From their support team:

> Hello,
>
> Thanks for reaching out. Our team is aware of an issue that is causing
>   the return-path to get added to the from address or removing the from
>   address. This can also cause the return-path to be displayed as the
>   subject line in some cases or return an empty subject line. The
>   engineers are currently determining the scope of this error as this
>   has just been seen and looking into resolving it. I will keep this
>   ticket open and let you know when I have an update.
>
> Thank you for your understanding,

Hopefully they will sort this out soon.